# Difficulties with NumPy ndarray syntax

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, multidimensional-array

## 2.

## Create and print a new bucketed array named 'buckets', such that all elements are floored by 10s. Then, print 'buckets'.

## Ex. 39 becomes 30, 42 becomes 40.

I'm having trouble understanding why this doesn't fill an ndarray, iterate through it, and set every non-multiple of 10 to the tens group to which it belongs. The error I'm getting is "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"

```
   print '2. '
   buckets = np.array(original)
   for i in buckets:
        for j in buckets:
            if buckets[i][j] % 10 != 0:
                buckets[i][j] = buckets[i][j] - buckets[i][j] % 10

   print buckets
   print '\n'
```

Comment: As a clarification, the line that threw the error was:

if buckets[i][j] % 10 != 0:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `for i in buckets` iterates through the value of each *row* of `buckets` not through the index of the rows.

You can get the shape of the array and then iterate through the range of indices instead:

```
for i in xrange(a.shape[0]):       # use 'range' in Python 3.x
    for j in xrange(a.shape[1]):   # use 'range' in Python 3.x
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm just unfamiliar with what shape[] does, could you elaborate a bit? No rush.

Comment: it returns the shape of the array (i.e. the max index of each dimension in the array).